# Mongoose model doesn't accept null value, but outputs fine in console.log

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, cryptography

I'm generating a token for Add User, which sends an email to the user with a generated token. The problem is that it's not working 100% of the time, and the token is sometimes seen as a null value.

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'confirmRegisterToken' of null
```

Code:

```
waterfall([
                    function(done) {
                        crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
                            token = buf.toString('hex');
                            done(err, token);
                        });
                    },

                    function(token, done) {
                        User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, user) {
                            console.log("USER FINDONE - TOKEN");
                            if(token === null) {
                                console.log("token is null");
                            }
                            user.confirmRegisterToken = token;
                            console.log("user.confirmRegisterToken: " + user.confirmRegisterToken);
                            user.isConfirmed = false;

                            user.save(function(err) {
                                done(err, token, user);
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    function(token, user, done) {
                        console.log("SMTP TRANSPORT - TOKEN");
                        var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                            service: 'Gmail',
                            auth: {
                                user: process.env.EMAIL,
                                pass: process.env.EMAIL_PW
                            }
                        });
                        var mailOptions = {
                            to: user.email,
                            from: process.env.EMAIL,
                            subject: '[redacted]',
                            text: 'Click on the link to confirm your registration.' +
                            'http://' + req.headers.host + '/confirm/' + token + '\n\n' + 
                            'This token expires in 24 hours!' +
                            'Your generated password is your given firstname and surname (no space & case sensitive)'
                        };
                        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
                            console.log('Mail sent');
                            res.redirect('/admin/adduser');
                            done(err, done, token);
                        });
                    }
                ], function(err) {
                    if(err) return next(err);
                    res.redirect('/admin/adduser');
                    done();
                });
```

I've given it a sample try of around 10 tries, and it works 50% of the time (strangely enough). Maybe it's something about the async and how it works, but I'm not sure so I need help for this one.

Comment: From the error you posted, I don't think it's the token that is `null`, it's the value of the user you queried from the DB that is `null`. Is there a possibility that a user with the email you are using to query the DB won't exist?

Comment: It sends the email regardless if it exists or not. I'm thinking the probable cause of this is the crypto not finishing because of the async(Not sure if this is how it works, I'm a beginner) then the mongoose assigns null because of it.

Comment: The error says `Cannot set property 'confirmRegisterToken' of null`, this means the object(`user`) to assign the `confirmRegisterToken` property to is `null` and in javascript, you can't set properties on null values(at least not like this). So this error is would be thrown regardless of the crypto finishing up or not. Can you try logging the user(fetched from the database) for cases when the error is thrown?, does it have a value of null at any point in time?